# How to emit selected radio to parent component?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I'm new with Typescript and I'm trying use defineEmits to send chosen radio to the parent component. I success with input field, send data to parent, but with radio is something different.

I declare array of radio in parent component with name and description, send to the child component and in child component I have button which for every click I change radio. The plan chosen radio use in parent component.

**Parent Component**

```
<script lang="ts">
import { useField, useForm } from 'vee-validate'
import { string } from 'yup'
export default defineComponent({
    components: {},
})
</script>

<script lang="ts" setup>
const subtitle: string | number = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.'
const { handleSubmit, errors } = useForm({
    validationSchema: {
        checked: string().required('enter the field.'),
    },
    initialValues: {
        checked: ''
    },
})
const { value: checked } = useField<string>('checked')
const arrayRadio: { name: string; description: string }[] = [
    {
        name: 'First',
        description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.',
    },
    {
        name: 'Second',
        description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.',
    },
]
</script>

<template>
    <main class="min-h-screen">
        <div class="base-container">Content</div>
        <InputRadio v-model="checked" :array-radio="arrayRadio" />
    </main>
</template>
```

**Child Component**

```
<script lang="ts" setup>

import { ref } from 'vue'

interface Props {
    subtitle?: string
    arrayRadio?: any
}

const props = withDefaults(defineProps<Props>(), {
    subtitle: '',
    arrayRadio: '',
})

const emit = defineEmits<{
    (event: 'update:arrayRadio', value: any): void
}>()

const { arrayRadio, subtitle } = toRefs(props)
const selected = ref(props.arrayRadio[1])

function updateInput(event: Event) {
    emit('update:arrayRadio', event.target.value)
}
</script>
<template>
    <div>
        <div v-for="plan in arrayRadio" :key="plan.name"
        class="mx-auto w-full max-w-md">
            <input id="html" v-model="selected" type="radio" :value="plan.name" @click="updateInput">
            <label for="html">{{ plan.name }}</label><br>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are emitting the `'update:arrayRadio'` event and listening to `array-radio`.

Vue can understand your emitted events from camelCase to kebab-case, but the problem here is the `update` before `arrayRadio`.

Try to rename it, like this:

```
function updateInput(event: Event) {
    emit('arrayRadio', event.target.value)
}

const emit = defineEmits<{
    (event: 'arrayRadio', value: any): void
}>()
```

You can even use the update on the name, but you have to use the same value across the components.